# Object Required in For Each Loop That Loops Through Range

Tags: excel, vba

So, I am trying to get the cell address of selected cells based on a `For Each` loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim company As String
    company = Range("H12").Value

    Dim companyRange, cell As Range
    companyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bleh List").Range("A2:A20")

    For Each cell In companyRange
        If cell.Value <> vbNullString And cell.Value = company Then
                Debug.Print "C : " & cell.Row
        End If
    Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

However everytime I try to run this, I am returned a `Object required` error on the first line of the loop.

What should have been so trivial is creating this problem > why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common misconception:

```
Dim companyRange, cell As Range
```

Only `cell` is a `Range`. `companyRange` is a `Variant`. You need:

```
Dim companyRange as Range, cell as Range
```

Then you're missing a `Set`.

```
Set companyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bleh List").Range("A2:A20")
```

Currently, `companyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bleh List").Range("A2:A20")` is a 2D Variant array, not the `Range` object that you are expecting to iterate over.

Comment: Exactly, and to better understand what happens with your variables, just drag them into the `Watches` window. It will tell you how these variable will behave. :)

Comment: @JvdV Sadly yes :( I always added them using the context menu. But dragging is so much easier that I feel so stupid.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, and BigBen Both you guys make me have an AHA moment if it comes down to VBA on a regular basis haha so it's all good. Knowledge shared :)